# Route is not working inside the controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-7

I did an autocomplete search function in Laravel using ajax. I tried to pass the route inside the href but it's working. I don't know how to pass the route in the controller. Please help me and give a solution on how to fix this.

```
$output = '';

        if (count($pro)>0)
        {
            foreach ($pro as $row)
            {
                $url = "{{ route('ProductDetail','.$row->prod_seo_title.') }}";

                $output .= '<li><a href="'.$url.'">'.$row->product_name.'</a></li>';
            }
        }
        else {

            $output .= '<li>'.'No results'.'</li>';
        }

        return $output;
```

**Now once I click the li tag URL is coming like this.**

> `https://testing.com/product-detail/%7B%7B%20route('ProductDetail','.Chiaro-Tote-1.')%20%7D%7D`

**I attached the screenshot here**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct give in href

```
$output .= '<li><a href="'.route('ProductDetail', $row->prod_seo_title).'">'.$row->product_name.'</a></li>';
```

Answer (score 3):

You are in a regular PHP file, this isn't Blade.

```
$url = route('ProductDetail', $row->prod_seo_title);
```

Comment: Perfect. It's working Thank you so much for your help.